# Staying 92 days in the Schengen area

Tags: visas, schengen

My girlfriend is from Peru and has been 83 days in France since July.
She is coming in December until February where we will both leave the Schengen area.
We planned to leave Europe for a few days (using http://www.schengen-calculator.com, it says she needs to leave for 11 days) but the cheapest tickets are 1 or 2 days after the date she has to leave.

Is it a big deal to leave after 92 days? Is there any other solution?

Comment: It is a big deal in that any overstay may adversely affect her ability to get a visa in the future.

Comment: You don't need to leave Europe, of course.  You can also go to European countries that are not part of Schengen.  The UK, Ireland, the channel islands, Croatia, Bulgaria, Serbia, Bosnia, Albania, Ukraine, Belarus, and others are possible choices.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, Peruvians need an advance visa for UK/Ireland, which would be hard to get when already in France. All the other choices will work.

Comment: Is Gibraltar another option?

Comment: We tried to go to Gibraltar in the past but it has the same immigration laws as UK. She will try to get a tourist visa for UK and leave 11 days to UK. I'm wondering if her days counter "resets" after the 180 days mark?
What I mean is, if she leaves and come back before her "reset day", so that she's at 90 days for her reset day, will it get back to 0 or does she has to return after her reset day?

Comment: The 90/180 counter does *not* reset on exit from Schengen to the UK. The 180 is taken as a moving window. I think you will need a back-up plan for refusal of a UK visa, as they may be reluctant to entertain the application in France, where she is merely a tourist.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus but someone who is planning a stay of several weeks having already stayed 83 days over the last five months will be able to effectively reset the clock by spending some number of days (apparently in this case 11 days) in the UK or another non-Schengen place.

Comment: @phoog You can't determine this without knowing which days were in Schengen and which not. If it was the last 83 days over the 5 months, then 11 days outside Schengen will be of no use at all.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus of course.  In making that statement I assume that Adrien Neveu has used the Schengen calculator correctly and that the calculator in question is in fact correctly programmed.  We at least know that it wasn't the last 83 days since some of those days were in July.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus She indeed stayed 83 days in total in Schengen over the 5 last months in two seperate occasions.
For the visa, she is applying in her home country.
She may buy her ticket to UK after entering France. Can she be refused her entrance because she doesn't have a valid ticket out, and because she only has 7 days left to stay?

Comment: @phoog No. I was choosing the limiting case. I didn't realize that we were talking about two large visits. But in no case is she going to get better than a day-for-day replenishment. If she gets the UK visa, I do not think they will be interested in how many days she has left in Schengen. But she can buy the round-trip ticket in advance, if you think they want to make sure at the border that she has a ticket out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I highly recommend not to overstay only to save a couple of euros.

If you save a huge amount of money (which I doubt) you can consider to do a city trip outside schengen area and so save those 3-4 days you need. However, this will be probably more money in total.

Edit: Relaxed is right, I somehow forgot this detail in the first part of my answer. Visa extension is only possible in the way o.m. described

Comment: This would not help at all in this case. Visa extensions are useful for people who have a visa about to expire but who haven't stayed 90 days yet. The OP's  girlfriend does not have nor need a visa but she would have stayed 90 days.

Answer (score 4):

> but the cheapest tickets are 1 or 2 days after the date she has to leave.

Then don't buy the **cheapest** tickets, buy the *cheaper* ones. Problems caused by overstaying your visa are far more costlier than the cost of paying some extra money for tickets.

Nobody is going to extend your visa just because you like to save some cash.

Comment: That second blockquote is misleading out of context. She would have to return to her home country _in order to apply for another visa to return to France_. For legality, she just has to get out of Schengen to some other country that she can enter legally.

Answer (score 4):

## Saving money is no excuse to overstay.

There might be reasons to extend a visa, for humanitarian or medical reasons and the like, but just saving money is not among them.

- In theory, she could try and get a D national visa from a Schengen state. In practice, that's not a realistic option in the timeframe.
- If you are an EU/EEA citizen, and if you can show a permanent domestic relationship, it might be possible to get a family permit in EU countries other than your homeland. Ask at Expatriates SE.

But most likely user Hanky Panky is right -- just get out within the time limit.

Comment: Some countries, including Spain and Italy, offer rights to the family of their citizens that are comparable to those offered to family of citizens of other EU countries.

Answer (score -1):

As the other answers point out, your girlfriend's life will be *much* easier if she leaves the Schengen zone on time. Let me add that there is a cheap flight using Air Europa, Madrid to Lima, Peru (below $1000 US most days). If you first holiday in a place where you can connect to this flight airside in Madrid, she could stay longer; there is no visa needed for the airside connection. Example, Rabat or Tangiers, Morocco have such connections, and Morocco has visa-free entry for Peruvians. So to the European countries @phoog gave in his answer, minus UK/Ireland. I just couldn't find a cheap connection from the countries in his list that I tried.